# eventstudie convert data into zoo object

Tags: r, events, zoo

I need to do a event studie for my thesis and plan to do it with the "eventstudie" package. My data (excel) didn't match the class necessary to do so, so I worked on it and by now it looks like this:

The events:

```
  'data.frame': 9 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ when: Date, format: "1925-04-29" "1925-03-21" "1925-10-02" "1927-04-27" ...
 $ name: chr  "Deutsche Bank" "Deutsche Bank" "Deutsche Bank" "Deutsche Bank" ...
```

The returns:

which began like this:

```
 str(db.kurs)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1455 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date         : POSIXct, format: "1925-01-02" "1925-01-03" "1925-01-05" "1925-01-06" ...
 $ Deutsche Bank: num  0.181 0.191 0.191 0.184 0.186 ...
```

now looks like this:

```
str (db.kurs3)
    'data.frame':   1455 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date         : Date, format: "1925-01-02" "1925-01-03" "1925-01-05" "1925-01-06" ...
 $ Deutsche.Bank: num  0.181 0.191 0.191 0.184 0.186 ...
```

the problem is, that it seems like the returns need to be a zoo object, something like this:

```
   'zoo' series from 2010-07-01 to 2013-03-28
Data: num [1:720, 1:30] 0.528 -1.731 -0.253 -0.317 -1.277 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
..$ : NULL
..$ : chr [1:30] "Bajaj.Auto" "BHEL" "Bharti.Airtel" "Cipla" ...
Index: Date[1:720], format: "2010-07-01" "2010-07-02" "2010-07-05" "2010-07-06" "2010-07-07"
```

simple stuff like `as.zoo` doesn't seem to work and I tried something like

```
db.returns <- zoo(db.kurs3, order.by =  as.Date("1925-01-02") + 0:1456)
```

but then it just takes every day as one step ahead in my return data, but since there was no trading on sundays that ist wrong, so it thinks my data is up to 1928-12-28 when instead I have data till 1929-12-31.

I really run out of ideas, how to convert it to a zoo object, so I can finally run a event study. I really hope someone here can help me, if you need more information, please give me a heads up!

Greetings

Nick